# How to set text position to the right of a Switch (like CheckBox)

Tags: java, android, xml

How to set the text position to the right of a Switch **without** align a Switch and a TextView in a LinearLayout ? I tried to override the CheckBox button style in my style.xml button but I don't know how to get the Switch button reference ?

Comment: Try setting `android:gravity="RIGHT"` attribute.

Comment: @TasosMoustakas no, it does not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've recently faced the same issue and as I didn't want to wrap my layout in an extra container like all the answers I came across suggested.

I found out that by adding `android:layoutDirection="rtl"` in the switch I can change the direction of the text because Android understands that this view is supposed to be read/used by a person who reads from right to left.

See full snippet below including an extra padding between the thumb and the text

```
<Switch
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:switchPadding="16dp"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:text="Your Text" />
```

---

## Update

I decided to update this for future reference as the claims in the comments are wrong and the op "unaccepted" this answer even when the question states "without align a Switch and a TextView in a LinearLayout" which the currently accepted answer does.

What the solution provided does is to tell that specific widget to change its layout orientation and by doing that it flip it from "LTR" (Left to right) to "RTL" (Right to left).

If you are not willing to nest layouts, this is a doable solution.

Testing

1. Set the widget layout orientation to "RTL"
2. Run the app
3. Go to Settings > Developer Options > Force RTL layout direction
4. Observe the layout

The direction of all the other widgets will flip to "RTL" as by the default they were on "LTR" and nothing will happen with the Switch as it is already in the right configuration.  Check the images below.

**Layout orientation "LTR" default**

[image]

**Layout orientation "RTL"**

[image]

Comment: Doesn't this cause problems with RTL layouts, though?

Comment: This also mirrors the switch itself which causes UX problems.

Comment: @Dogcat have you read the op question before downvoting my answer? When you change the layout direction it obviously would change the switch direction. That's a solution of many and as the op didn't provide requirements around the desired UI it solved his problem as mine several times. If you are looking for a specific solution which fits your UI/UX you should post your own question or try to follow the answer below.

Comment: Yep, I have and your solution goes beyond what the OP asked. What I was trying to say is that aplying "rtl" doesn't only change the text aligment, it also flips the switch drawable itself: it becomes "circle on the right when inactive - circle on left when active". That indeed is a UI/UX problem which will only confuse your users because in virtually every other app it's vice versa for LTR spelling systems.

Comment: That's why is called "layoutDirection", it will obviously flips everything. The mistake you are making is to assume that all UI/UX requirements are exactly the same which is completely wrong. Even the Material Design Guideline is just a guideline which even Google itself does not follow all the time. So in the real world, a Switch will be used in different situations being grouped with other widgets or by itself and that's why this solution worked for the op and many times for me.

Answer (score 5):

Two ways are there but as negative padding is not recommended so the 2nd way.

**=>** Using a separate text view

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Switch
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/switch1" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="This is a switch"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT** - There's no direct way but using Negative padding, A parent Layout or Any custom library.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30702713/how-to-change-text-direction-to-the-right-slide-of-switch-in-android) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023350/how-to-change-switch-text-to-right-side-in-android).
 Forget this and use [this library](https://github.com/GwonHyeok/StickySwitch).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is exactly what I don't want to do.